# liquibase pro key issue

Tags: maven, liquibase, license-key

I got liquibase trial pro key,but project  Validation Failed with message "Change Type 'pro:createFunction' is not allowed without a valid Liquibase Pro License."

i tried maven config like this

```
<configuration>
    <changeLogFile>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/config/liquibase/master.xml</changeLogFile>
    <diffChangeLogFile>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog/${maven.build.timestamp}_changelog.xml</diffChangeLogFile>
    <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
    <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/FreshHipster</url>
    <defaultSchemaName></defaultSchemaName>
    <username>FreshHipster</username>
    <password></password>
    <referenceUrl>hibernate:spring:domain.folder?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect&amp;hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy&amp;hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy</referenceUrl>
    <verbose>true</verbose>
    <logging>debug</logging>
    <contexts>!test</contexts>
    <liquibaseProLicenseKey>ABwwGg...</liquibaseProLicenseKey>

 </configuration>
```

and this

```
<configuration>
  <propertyFile>liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
<diffChangeLogFile>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog/${maven.build.timestamp}_changelog.xml</diffChangeLogFile>
<verbose>true</verbose>
<logging>debug</logging>
<contexts>!test</contexts>
</configuration>
```

liquibase.properties

(comannd "*liquibase status*" in folder with file liquibase.properties shows:
*Liquibase Pro 4.3.1 by Datical licensed to Liquibase Pro Evaluation until ср march. 24 05:00:00 ALMT 2021* )

```
changeLogFile: ${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/config/liquibase/master.xml
url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/FreshHipster
username: FreshHipster 
password: 
driver: org.postgresql.driver
referenceUrl: hibernate:spring:domain.folder?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect&amp;hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy&amp;hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy
liquibaseProLicenseKey: ABwwG...
```

Answer (score 0):

I launched spring boot wrong.
I had to luacnh with maven mvn spring-boot:run